# HTTP session unavailable while running through domain name

Tags: apache, session-cookies, http-proxy

I made a Chess web game (in Dart), deploying to Linux + Apache (behind a proxy). When accessing with public IP, the game ran smoothly. However, when accessing through domain name, the game failed to run. I used both cookie (for token) and HTTP session (for game data), matching this token between cookie and HTTP session.

Here is my Apache setting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

I think the issue might be from cookie behind Apache proxy. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need   `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomian` to make sure the domain= in your session cookie is self-referential.  Looking at the actual headers sent in e.g. developer tools would probably make it clear.

Comment: I tried the app locally. The app ran smoothly on Chrome and Opera, but failed on Firefox and Safari. I think the app may have other issues. Thanks anyway.